# Calling a end point in confluence wiki page

Tags: backend, confluence

I have a endpoint point which has a body..I want to take values of end point from confluence (wiki) and then call that endpoint with confluence scripting. Can any one provide me a detail steps on how can we achieve this?

I am not getting the steps.. can anyone help me how can I proceed here

Answer (score 0):

In order to make things easier you can try to use function confluence.get_page_by_id from https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html

An example is the below that I have already personally tested:

```
from atlassian import Confluence
confluence = Confluence(
    url='https://site_name.atlassian.net',
    username='email',
    password='token_api',
    cloud=True)


f = open('log.txt','w')

     


pg = confluence.get_page_by_id(2097171, expand='body.storage')
pg_content = pg['body']
print(pg_content, file=f) # Python 3.x

print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------', file=f)


pg = confluence.get_page_by_id(2097171, expand='body.view')
pg_content = pg['body']
print(pg_content, file=f) # Python 3.x
```